# How can I retrieve the coordinates of a point in a kdtree given that point's tree index?

Tags: python, kdtree

For example, suppose I have created a kdtree from the points in a 2-d array.  Then I run a nearest neighbor query on some point (represented as a pair of x-y coordinates) asking for the 8 nearest neighbors to that point.  This returns two lists: (1) a list of 8 distances to neighbors of the given pint, and (2) a list of tree indices for those neighbors.

Suppose now that I want to take one of those tree indices and get the x-y coordinates of that point?  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

FYI there is a `data` attribute that contains the coordinates of the tree: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

So you can get your coordinates via

```
tree.data[index]
```

Here's a full example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

pts = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)])

# Build tree
tree = KDTree(pts)

# Query tree for points within distance=2 of (1,1)
idx = tree.query_ball_point([1,1],r=2)
print(idx)
```

which yields

```
[0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2]
```

Then to get the coordinates of these indicies,

```
# Get coordinates of the indices
print(tree.data[idx])
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 2.]
 [1. 3.]
 [2. 1.]
 [2. 2.]
 [3. 1.]]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that illustrates how to use this?  I have read that scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html page several times, and don't see any mention of this.  Also, would you happen to know where I could find documentation or a tutorial on this scipy package.  The webpage you reference, which I have seen before, is almost totally incomprehensible.

Comment: Added example. The docs are where I found this "feature" after finding your post, so I don't know I'd agree they're incomprehensible. You do need to know what an attribute of a Python object is, though, for it to make sense.

Comment: This is very helpful, and I appreciate your taking the trouble to write all this out.  I don't think I would ever have been able to get this from that scipy webpage, but I do have to admit that I'm still learning Python.

Comment: No worries. It took me awhile to understand classes (which is what "tree" is) but they're just buckets where you can store data (attributes) and functions (methods). If you use an IDE with tab auto-complete (like Spyder), you can type "tree." and see what methods and attributes are available for the tree object. If this answers the question, please accept the answer :)

Comment: How do I "accept the answer".  I don't see anything about this on this web page.

Comment: I think there is a little grey check mark near the votes counter beside the answer you can click that should turn it green. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for a visual.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, one of my students provided the answer.  There is no kdtree method that returns this information, but you can get it from the original lists used to create the tree.  The x-y coordinates of the points used to construct the tree are taken from two lists, one of the x coordinates, and one of the y-coordinates.  Then, when you do a kdtree query, the list of indexes returned by the query can be used as indexes into the two original lists to get back the original x-y pairs.